# Cant add variables to a class?

Tags: python

Ok, so i'm really starting to get annoyed at this. I can't seem to figure out what it is? Some are saying it is indentation but i've tried that.

Here is my code:

```
class player(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.nation_name = None
    self.race = None
    self.name = None

    self.special_unit = None
    self.special_unitsize = 0
    self.regular_army = 50
    self.army_size = special_unitsize +regular_army
    self.army_power = 250

    self.IceColdCoins = 0
    self.gold = 100

    self.taxincome = 45
    self.mineincome = 0
    self.recruitrate = 30
    self.totalincome = taxincome + mineincome

    self.num_of_mines = 1
    self.num_of_towns = 0
    self.num_of_cities = 1
    self.num_of_fort = 0

    self.wait_till_upgrade = 0
```

And every time I try to add any type of variable it doesn't allow it saying: 
attribute error (example) is not defined.

I did a test and well same error. Copy code and add a variable and make an if statement about the variable it won't work.

Comment: You haven't actually shown _how_ you're trying to add variables. Who are "some" in relation to indentation?

Comment: `special_unitsize` and `self.special_unitsize` are two different things, and you should be seeing an error to that effect as soon as you try to define `self.army_size`. Are you actually creating an instance of `player`? E.g. `p = player()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to use `self`:

```
self.taxincome = 45
self.mineincome = 0
self.totalincome = taxincome + mineincome   # there is no 'taxincome', etc.
```

The first two lines do not make `taxincome` and `mineincome`  variables in the local (or global) namespace, but attributes of `self`:

```
self.taxincome = 45
self.mineincome = 0
self.totalincome = self.taxincome + self.mineincome  # note the 'self'
```

The same goes for `special_unitsize` and `regular_army`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me and for the fast reply!